# Checking if registry value is equal to 1 is not working correctly

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

I have slopped together bits of PowerShell to remote query a list of machines, stored in a .csv file, for a registry value.  If the registry key's value is equal to '1', the script should then create a text file using the machine's name as the name of the text file.

Everything works great.  The script runs happily without any errors.  The problem is that when I go back and remotely check a targeted registry value, I find that the value isn't 1.  The script is simply creating a file for every line in the .csv.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT*** I found ***a*** problem  I had a typo in the $key variable for the registry path.  7/17/2013 2:21p

```
$File = Import-Csv 'c:\temp\machines.csv'

foreach ($line in $file)
{
  $machinename = $line.machinename
  trap [Exception] {continue}
  $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("LocalMachine",$MachineName)
  $key = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\WinLogon"
  $regkey = ""
  $regkey = $reg.opensubkey($key)
  $keyValue = ""
  $keyValue = $regKey.GetValue('AutoAdminLogon')

  if ($keyValue = "1")
  {
    try
    {
      $textFile = New-Item -Path "c:\temp\autologin" -Name $MachineName -ItemType "File"
    }
    catch
    {
      $msg = $_
      $msg
    }
  }
  $Results = $MachineName , $keyValue
  Write-host $Results

  #Output Below Here:
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PowerShell `=` is an assignment operator, not a comparison operator. Change this line:

```
if ($keyValue = "1")
```

into this:

```
if ($keyValue -eq "1")
```

For more information see [`Get-Help about_Operators`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx).

You're making this way too complicated, BTW. Something like this should suffice:

```psh
$keyname = 'SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\WinLogon'

Import-Csv 'C:\temp\machines.csv' | % {
  $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("LocalMachine",
           $_.machinename)
  $key = $reg.OpenSubkey($keyname)
  $value = $key.GetValue('AutoAdminLogon')
  if ($value -eq "1") {
    $filename = Join-Path "c:\temp\autologin" $_.machinename
    try {
      touch $filename
      $textFile = Get-Item $filename
    } catch {
      $_
    }
  }
  Write-Host ($_.machinename , $value)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the catch Ansgar!  Also, thank you for the simplified version above.

Comment: The last line of the simplified version is referring to variables in the original script that do not exist in the simplified version. I think the last line be something like: 
Write-Host ($_.machinename , $value)

Comment: `$key.GetValue('')` gives you the `(Default)` value