# Powershell output to file assistance

Tags: powershell

I am using this question as my base reference [Powershell - Query remote registry key value and generate text file IF value equals 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710364/powershell-query-remote-registry-key-value-and-generate-text-file-if-value-equ/22351034?noredirect=1#comment33972039_22351034)

I am trying to find the value of a registry key and output that to a file.

I modifed the code in that link to look like this.

```
$keyname = 'Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU'

Import-Csv 'C:\computers.csv' | % {
$reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("LocalMachine",
   $_.machinename)
$key = $reg.OpenSubkey($keyname)
$value = $key.GetValue('AUoptions')
Write-Host ($_.machinename , $value) | write-output "c:\computerresults.csv"
```

The script works correctly until I get to the | write-output.  I cannot get it to dump the results to a file.  I tried export-csv as well.

Any assistance given would be greatly appericated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a closing curly brace to your % loop. I have inserted it, and modified the last line to give you the output you desire (pretty sure, not tested but it should work.

```
New-Object PSObject @{MachineName=$_.machinename;Value=$value} } | Export-CSV "c:\computerresults.csv" -NoTypeInfo
```

That will output a series of custom objects that have 2 values each, MachineName and Value. Then it takes all those objects and exports them to a CSV. The -NoTypeInfo is so that you don't get a line at the top stating what kind of object it was exported from.

Comment: If one of these answers resolves your question please select that answer as the solution to close out the question.

Answer (score 2):

`Write-Host` breaks the pipeline. Use `Write-Output` instead when you want to display information within a piped command.

Also, `Write-Output` is not the command you're looking for to export data. Look into `Export-Csv` and `Out-File` for file output.

[Export-Csv](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849932.aspx)

[Out-File](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849882.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.  This is what I ended up using

```
$keyname = 'Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU'

Import-Csv 'C:\computers.csv' | % {
$reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("LocalMachine",
       $_.machinename)
$key = $reg.OpenSubkey($keyname)
$value = $key.GetValue('AUoptions')
New-Object PSObject @{MachineName=$_.machinename;Value=$value} 
Write-Host ($_.machinename , $value)
} | out-file "c:\computerresults.csv"
```

@TheMadTechnician.  If I used the Export-csv (either with the write-host or without) I got this as my output 
IsReadOnly  IsFixedSize IsSynchronized  Keys    Values  SyncRoot    Count
FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   System.Collections.Hashtable+KeyCollection  System.Collections.Hashtable+ValueCollection    System.Object   2

So I combined what both you and @kohlbrr provided and come up with a working solution that displayed the results to me on the screen as well as dropping them in the file.

Thanks again.